# When should we use an enum over a regular constant variable?

Tags: java, enums

An enum is a specialized class that holds a set of constants. If we wanted to declare a field (variable) to be a constant in Java, we would use the keyword final. When should we use an enum over a regular constant variable?

Comment: remember that enums are not "variables that point to some value that your code _actually_ works with", like constants: they _are_ that value. So there's no possibility of having constants that your code sees as being equal: enums are unique and you use them directly, you don't use the "real" values they point to, like constants.

Answer (score 7):

Advantage of `enum`: type-safety

For example, considering the months, if we have constants as `int` (`static final int JANUARY = 1`)<sup>**1**</sup> then a variable or method parameter must be declared as `int` and would accept any integer value , valid or not(e.g. `setMonth(123)` or `setMonth(0)`).
If we have an `enum`, then the variables or method parameters can only accept its values - errors (wrong constants) can be detected at compile time (exception: `null` which can also be assigned/passed instead of an `enum`, like any reference type).

<sup>**1**: not the same definition as from `Calendar` (JANUARY = 0)</sup>

---

Official Oracle tutorial [Enum Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html):

> You should use enum types any time you need to represent a fixed set of constants. That includes natural enum types such as the planets in our solar system and data sets where you know all possible values at compile time—for example, the choices on a menu, command line flags, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Enums are typically used for groups of constants that are related. For example, `shirt_sizes` may be an enum of `Small, Medium, Large, X-Large` and so on. These will always be the same and we know what they are at the time we write the program.

If you want further reading that helps to explain why we use enums, check out this article https://crunchify.com/why-and-for-what-should-i-use-enum-java-enum-examples/